# Linking.addEventListener not getting event

Tags: ios, react-native

Im developing an app with a React Native and Ruby on Rails backend.

The following flow is working:

1. You click a button to authenticate
2. Button runs the React Native code below hits the ruby on rails end point.
3. The end point redirects back to the app.
4. URl Scheme is working.

**Problem:**

**The `console.log("NOT BEING HIT")` is not being hit. Which means there is no event. What am I doing wrong?**

```
export function instagramOauth (callback) {
  var state = Math.random() + ''

  Linking.addEventListener('url', handleUrl)

  function handleUrl (event) {

    console.log("NOT BEING HIT")

    var [, query_string] = event.url.match(/\#(.*)/)
    var query = shittyQs(query_string)
    if (state === query.state) {
      callback(null, query.access_token, query.uid)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Oauth2 security error'))
    }
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleUrl)
  }

  Linking.openURL([
    'http://localhost:3000/mobile/instagram_authentication'
  ].join(''))
}
```

Incase you want to see the end point.

```
def token
  @response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => mobile_token_url)
  instagram_user = InstagramUserCreator.new(user_params)
  if instagram_user.find_or_create
    #TODO: Redirect with token in url
    redirect_to 'taddarmobileapp://'
  else
    #TODO
    redirect_to 'taddarmobileapp://'
  end
end
```

Comment: What is Linking that you are calling .addEventListener on?

Comment: Same issue. Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Also having this issue. Still waiting for a resolution, any updates?